# jenkins get result from triggered job and use it in other stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

i have a jenkins pipeline witch triggers another pipeline. is it possible to save the result from this triggerd job pipeline in the first pipeline?
Example pipelie 1:

```
stage('do something') {
  when { expression { params.true == true } }
    steps {
      script {
        env.var = build job: 'jenkinsjob2',
                          parameters: [

                          ]

      print(env.var)
      }
    }
}
```

jenkinsjob2 pipeline:

```
stage('do something else') {
  when { expression { params.false == false } }
  steps{
    script {
      my_new_result = sh( returnStdout: true, script: 'python script.py')
      println my_new_result // echo 12345
```

I now want to use the result 12345 from the second job in env.var from the first pipeline.
is this possible?
i got for env.var = org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@6c4ddc63 and not 12345

KR
Marvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this pipeline to get an idea of what to do.

```
 stage('do something') {

        steps
                {
                    script {
                        def job = build job: "jenkinsjob2",parameters: []
                        env.my_new_result = job.buildVariables.my_new_result

                    }sh "echo  ${env.my_new_result}" 
                }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer
that throws "null"
is .buildVariable the right method to call? i am thinking about somethilg like getResult()
any further ideas?

Comment: Ahh got it. i have to set the variable in jenkinsjob2 to env.my_new_result
thanks a lot